# Change number of rows shown in datatable in Backpack for Laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

Is there another way to change how many rows are shown in the table other than overwriting the list.blade.php file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [little-known API method](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-full-api#usage-level-3-sometimes), but you can do that by calling this in your EntityCrudController:

```
$this->crud->setDefaultPageLength(10); // number of rows shown in table view
```

Comment: How to list all? Is there any way I can setDefaultPageLength as 'All'?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time has passed. At the moment with the current version of Backpack (v 4.1.X) there is a setting in the configuration file in `config/backpack/crud.php` named `defaultPageLength` that controls the page length globally. If page length for a single CRUD controller should be changed, then `$this->crud->setDefaultPageLength(50)` is still the way to go.

More details can be found here: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-api#page-length